# Read .json from maven /resource in java (lib: org.json)

Tags: java, json, org.json

In my maven project, I have stored a .json (in the folder `resources` which is next to the folder `java`). The name of the file and it's path relative to the resources folder is given.

I want to:

1. read this file
2. convert it to org.json.JSONArray

I prefer not to import libraries other than org.json, but if really needed, other stuff from JRE system library (java8) is allowed too.

Addition notes:

- do I have to add something to pom.xml?
- this is done within a static method
- this will run on a server

Comment: Write the code and then share the piece of code where you are stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your module path is ./src/main/resources/ this worked for me.

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/data.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```